# undefined method should_receive' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I am writing UserLogin feature in cucumber and there I have to test if user logged in successfully. Everything goes well except last line:

```
Then I should be redirected to my home page
```

Problem is that it isn't usual login and it needs ticket. Ticket is obtained from ApplicationController#login_ticket. I want to stub it so I wrote this web step:

```
Then(/^I should be redirected to my home page$/) do
  ApplicationController.should_receive(:login_ticket).and_return("2081677")
  current_path.should eq root_path
end
```

But it fails with message:

> Then I should be redirected to my home page              #
>   features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:13
>         undefined method `should_receive' for ApplicationController:Class (NoMethodError)
>         ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in`/^I should be redirected to my home page$/'
>         features/UserLogin.feature:9:in `Then I should be redirected to my home page'

What could be problem here?

Answer (score 1):

should_receive isn't really stubbing, it's setting a mock-expectation. Try this below instead:

```
ApplicationController.stub(:login_ticket) { "2081677" }
```

You'll also need to verify that RSpec is active

```
require 'cucumber/rspec/doubles'
```

more: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Mocking-and-Stubbing-with-Cucumber